# Как в kivy сделать обратный возврат окна

Tags: python, kivy

помогите мне пожалуйста. Пишу программу на kivy, и не могу понять, как сделать так, чтоби после нажатия на кнопку "Назад", анимация перехода, била обратной, потому что, экран всё время движется в одном направлении. Буду очень благодарен, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Для кнопки в .kv файле указать следующее:

```
root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
```

или

```
root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!